# The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat

getting compilation error

in console it is showing:

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.0)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol (^0.8.1)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol (^0.8.0)

----------------------------code------------------------------------------

pragma solidity <=0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

hardhat.config.js

solidity: {
compilers: [
{
version: "0.8.0",
},
{
version: "0.8.1",
settings: {},
},
],
},

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a version mismatch between the Solidity version pragma statement in your contract and the OpenZeppelin contract files. The OpenZeppelin contracts require a Solidity compiler version of 0.8.0 or higher, as denoted by ^0.8.0, while your contract file specifies a version less than or equal to 0.8.0 with <=0.8.0.

To fix, modify the pragma statement in your contract file lik this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

You can also update your hardhat file & remove the additional compiler configuration for version "0.8.1"

```
solidity: {
  compilers: [
    {
      version: "0.8.0",
    },
  ],
},
```